# Need help to rephrase this code to avoid writing SOQL query inside for loop

Tags: apex, trigger

```
private static void validateBeforeUpdateLockDown(Map<Id,Med_Question_Section_Mapper__c> newMQSecMapperMap, List<Med_Question_Section_Mapper__c> oldMQSecMapperList) {
    for(Med_Question_Section_Mapper__c cObject : oldMQSecMapperList) {
        Med_Question_Section__c parent = [SELECT External_Id__c, Transaction_ID__c FROM Med_Question_Section__c WHERE ID =: cObject.Med_Question_Section__c];
        String errorMsg = trip_ValidationService.validateLockDown(parent.External_Id__c, parent.Transaction_ID__c)
```

Comment: Can you please confirm newMQSecMapperMap and oldMQSecMapperList will have same Ids?

Comment: yes manish these are IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Changes i did in your code

- Create a separate `Set<ID> of ids to store cObject.Med_Question_Section__c`
- Write SOQL to get the records using a set of Ids.
- Create a map to store Ids, with record `Map<Id,Med_Question_Section__c> mapOfIdToRecord = new Map<Id,Med_Question_Section__c>();`
- At the last for loop you will get the record from Map.

---

```
Set<Id> setOfIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Med_Question_Section_Mapper__c cObject : oldMQSecMapperList) {
      setOfIds.add(cObject.Med_Question_Section__c);
    }

    Map<Id,Med_Question_Section__c> mapOfIdToRecord = new Map<Id,Med_Question_Section__c>();

    for(Med_Question_Section__c parent = [SELECT Id,External_Id__c, Transaction_ID__c FROM Med_Question_Section__c WHERE ID =: cObject.Med_Question_Section__c]){
        mapOfIdToRecord.put(Id,parent);
    }

    for(Med_Question_Section_Mapper__c obj : oldMQSecMapperList){
        Med_Question_Section__c parent = mapOfIdToRecord.get(obj.Med_Question_Section__c);
    }
```

Comment: thanks Sarvesh this is helpful.

Comment: If this answer solved the question, please mark the answer solved to close the question. thanks!

Comment: @sarveshkumar Begging for votes and accepted answers is considered very rude.